# SQL query to find dates where more records were active

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
prod StartDate   ENDdate
----------------------------
a    1789-04-01  1799-12-14
b    1797-03-04  1826-07-04
c    1801-03-04  1826-07-04
d    1809-03-04  1836-06-28
e    1817-03-04  1831-07-04
```

I am trying to find a solution for above scenario but not able to get the logic. could you please help me on this.

the question is to find the start-date and end-date where most number of product were active.

For example : in above sample data, between 1817-03-04 to 1826-07-04  there are almost 4 products(b,c,d,e) were active (3409 days ) and 1 product(a) was active between 1789-04-01 to 1799-12-14.

The results should be like

```
prod_count StartDate       ENDdate
-----------------------------------
4          1817-03-04  1826-07-04
1          1789-04-01  1799-12-14
```

Comment: You can't assign a random sample as a  data range for comparision without having a criteria to chose that time period. There should be specific predefined interval to measure it (such as over a decade, a century, a quarter century etc ) to compare and categorise them as ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test table and data:

```
create table startend ( prod, startdate, enddate )
as
select 'a', date'1789-04-01', date'1799-12-14' from dual union all
select 'b', date'1797-03-04', date'1826-07-04' from dual union all
select 'c', date'1801-03-04', date'1826-07-04' from dual union all
select 'd', date'1809-03-04', date'1836-06-28' from dual union all
select 'e', date'1817-03-04', date'1831-07-04' from dual ; 

SQL> select * from startend;
PROD  STARTDATE  ENDDATE    
a     01-APR-89  14-DEC-99  
b     04-MAR-97  04-JUL-26  
c     04-MAR-01  04-JUL-26  
d     04-MAR-09  28-JUN-36  
e     04-MAR-17  04-JUL-31
```

Let's assume that we need to find/examine every possible combination of STARTDATE and ENDDATE.  We could use a JOIN like the one in the inline view below.  In this query, the rownum values have been renamed to: ERA (and will be used for GROUP BY at a later stage).

```
  select 
    to_char( startdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') start_
  , to_char( enddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')   end_
  , enddate - startdate as duration
  , rownum as era
  from ( 
    select distinct
      S1.startdate
    , S2.enddate
    from startend S1 
      join startend S2 on S1.startdate < S2.enddate
  ) 
;

-- result
START_     END_         DURATION        ERA
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1789-04-01 1836-06-28      17254          1
1789-04-01 1826-07-04      13607          2
1801-03-04 1831-07-04      11079          3
1809-03-04 1836-06-28       9978          4
1817-03-04 1836-06-28       7056          5
1817-03-04 1831-07-04       5235          6
1801-03-04 1826-07-04       9253          7
1809-03-04 1826-07-04       6331          8
1789-04-01 1831-07-04      15433          9
1797-03-04 1799-12-14       1015         10
1797-03-04 1826-07-04      10713         11
1797-03-04 1831-07-04      12539         12
1817-03-04 1826-07-04       3409         13
1789-04-01 1799-12-14       3909         14
1797-03-04 1836-06-28      14360         15
1801-03-04 1836-06-28      12900         16
1809-03-04 1831-07-04       8157         17

17 rows selected.
```

The conditions you need seem to be as follows (see the WHERE clause):

```
-- test dates: from your question
select prod
from startend
where startdate <= date'1817-03-04' and startdate < date'1826-07-04'
  and enddate   > date'1817-03-04' and enddate   >= date'1826-07-04'
;

-- result
b
c
d
e
```

Final step: combine the ideas behind the first 2 queries, something like (Oracle 11g):

```
select count(*)                        as "prod_count"
, to_char( E.startdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) as "StartDate"
, to_char( E.enddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )   as "EndDate"
from 
(
    select startdate, enddate, rownum as era
    from 
    (
      select distinct
        S1.startdate
      , S2.enddate
      from startend S1 join startend S2 on S1.startdate < S2.enddate
    )
) E 
join 
(
    select distinct prod, startdate, enddate from startend
) P  
on    
      ( P.startdate <= E.startdate and P.startdate < E.enddate )
  and ( P.enddate   >  E.startdate and P.enddate   >= E.enddate )
--
group by era, E.startdate, E.enddate
order by 2, 3
;
```

Result

```
prod_count StartDate  EndDate   
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 1789-04-01 1799-12-14
         2 1797-03-04 1799-12-14
         1 1797-03-04 1826-07-04
         2 1801-03-04 1826-07-04
         3 1809-03-04 1826-07-04
         1 1809-03-04 1831-07-04
         1 1809-03-04 1836-06-28
         4 1817-03-04 1826-07-04
         2 1817-03-04 1831-07-04
         1 1817-03-04 1836-06-28

10 rows selected.
```

See also: [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f3ec39e9e44424177b00aa528823e86).  When working with Oracle 12c (or 18c), you could use CROSS APPLY (instead of JOIN ... ON ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan, it work. even i tried bit similar  but mine giving some issue when product count is less then 2.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS prod_count, StartDate, ENDdate
FROM XXX
GROUP BY StartDate, ENDdate;
```

-- It works with equal StartDate and ENDdate values.

2) Another idea can be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS prod_count, StartDate, ENDdate
(
    SELECT StartDate, ENDdate, (StartDate - ENDdate) AS TimePeriod 
    FROM XXX
) AS X2
GROUP BY TimePeriod;
```

-- It works with equal time period.

Sorry I don't have Oracle instance access so its from hand without previous test so there can be some inaccuracy.